# Static scope inside has_many in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm having the following issue. I want to set a certain amount of has_many relations in a model, with names taken from a passed array (or in this case, the keys of a hash). Like this:

```
object_class_names = {:foo => FooClass, :bar => BarClass}

for key_name in object_class_names.keys
  has_many  "#{key_name}_objects".to_sym,
            -> {where(var: key_name)},
            :class_name => object_class_names[key_name]
end
```

This results in two has_many relations: `some_object.foo_objects` & `some_object.bar_objects`. Both have a specific class_name and a specific scope, set in the where clause in the lambda. However, because the scope is a lambda it gets the key_name in the where clause dynamically. This is the last known key_name variable, which is the last one in the loop, in this case 'bar'. So both `foo_objects` and `bar_objects` return a set of objects scoped with `where(var: "bar")`.

Usually the lambda makes a great way to pass in dynamic scopes in has_many relations, but in this case I don't really need it. Is it possible to set a static scope inside a has_many relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [Hash#`each_pair`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair) here:

```
object_class_names.each_pair do |key_name, klass|
  has_many :"#{key_name}_objects", -> { where(var: key_name) }, class_name: klass.to_s
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Both this and ArtOfCode's answer work, although I think this solution is slightly more elegant. I have no clue though as to why. What is the difference between this loop and the one I used? I would say you'd end up with the same problem, but for some reason this works, and my code doesn't. Ah well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @KobusPost I'm falling asleep at the moment, typing from mobile, but I'll try to find a moment tomorrow to check and explain what was wrong with the one you had (I should confess - never had I used `for` loop in Ruby, not even once.. :))

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? I haven't tested it, but the theory is that you're accessing the specific key name you want, rather than the last-known key name.

```
object_class_names.keys.each_with_index do |key_name, index|
  has_many "#{key_name}_objects",
           -> { where(:var => object_class_names.keys[index]) },
           :class_name => object_class_names[key_name]
end
```